# How to change properties of shortcut .lnk file located in Quick Launch startup/Taskbar?

Tags: vbscript

I tried below script but able to change shortcut properties for "Desktop" stored items only but wanted to change for the items stored in below locations:

1. C:\Users\bijender\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\
2. C:\Users\bijender\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\StartMenu\

VBScript below:

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\AE Client.LNK")

lnk.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe" \\rrscwpappimg02\Workflow\CWF\AppEnabler\CombinedCWF.xml
lnk.Description = "AE Client"
lnk.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hyland\Application Enabler\"
lnk.Save
```

Comment: Something not working if you change the path from `wsc.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\AE Client.LNK"` to a file in one of those locations?

Comment: The `lnk.TargetPath` looks invalid to me shouldn't it be `lnk.TargetPath = """C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe"" ""\\rrscwpappimg02\Workflow\CWF\AppEnabler\CombinedCWF.xml"""` or something similar? At the moment it isn't a valid string and should generate an error.

Comment: I think it could be that if you use those paths in the script the value in the file on the disk gets changed but not in the pinned item on taskbar and in start menu. This has something to do with how annoyingly microsoft handled the pinning via registry + hdd entry for those files. Could also be that it requires a reboot, but before I try to come up with a horrible hack to bypass this let's wait if that is even the problem

Comment: Thanks for the info.
@AnsgarWiechers, I also tried that but did not work.

Comment: "Did not work" is an insufficient problem description. How *exactly* did it "not work"? Did you fix the `TargetPath` value as Lankymart pointed out?